# Fortran splats my output to asterisks - why?

Tags: io, formatting, fortran

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around formatting statements in Fortran.

Without formatting my output, this is what I do (inside a loop, so this happens a few times):

```
write(*,*) t*1E9
```

`t` here is `real*8`. The output is just what I'd expect - increments of 0.1, with some rounding errors:

```
0.0000000000000000     
0.10000000000000001     
0.20000000000000001     
0.29999999999999999     
0.40000000000000002     
0.50000000000000000     
0.59999999999999998     
0.69999999999999996     
0.79999999999999993     
0.89999999999999991     
0.99999999999999989
```

Now, I try to add a format statement:

```
write(*, '(F1.2)') t*1E9
```

and (with everything else the same) instead I get only asterisks in my output:

```
**
**
(etc...)
```

I've tried to read up on how this should work, and I can't figure out why this is happening. I've tried formats with more space for digits (`F15.15` just gives me more asterisks per line), I've tried moving the format statement to its own, labelled line... I just can't seem to get the output I'd like.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Fortran format statements are defined as:

`Fw.d`, where w is the number of characters to be used in total, and d is the number of characters after the decimal point. Here you are telling it that you need a float, that is 1 character wide in total, and 2 characters after the decimal point, something that is obviously not correct. So to get, for example, a float that is 4 characters in total, with 3 decimal places, you'd write:

```
write(*, '(F4.3)') t*1E9
```

See http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap05/format.html

Also, I should mention that the asterisks are indicative that the number cannot be displayed in the format stated.

EDIT:

Adding in the comment from george below:

"For E format the fieldwidth has to be at least 7 more than the number of decimals, eg E15.8. Four for the exponent, two for the lead 0. one for a possible '-'. I usually add one more extra space so numbers don't run together, E16.8"

Comment: Thanks! That explains a lot =) However, it doesn't help me all the way - when I apply the same principles, although with e.g. `E5.4`, for other doubles (i.e. `real*8`s), one column with order of magnitude 1e-2 - 1e-3 and one with order of magnitude 1e2, it gives med asterisks for those columns (the time column works as expected). My entire format string at the moment: `F4.2,E10.8,E10.8`.

Comment: For E format the fieldwidth has to be at least 7 more than the number of decimals, eg E15.8. Four for the exponent, two for the lead 0. one for a possible '-'. I usually add one more extra space so numbers don't run together, E16.8 ..

Comment: @george that is important enough to be in answer I think. that was the more exactly the answer to my problem as well. thanks!

Comment: **Edit:** my problem was solved by specifying a max number of columns in my format statment ``'(200(f16.8))'``, along with my implied do-loop that read the columns.