# Create a string by numeric values

Tags: string, fortran

I'm trying to create a string putting together various numeric values, so that I can use it to modify the name of the output files for the program.
My code looks something like

```
PROGRAM main

common filename
character (len=35) :: filename


mass=1.00E+10
radius=1.00E+03
nu=03.0
tau = 0.5

write(filename,7893) "_M",mass,"_nu",nu,"_tau",tau,"_Reff",radius
7893    format(A2,E6.2E2,A3,F4.1,A4,F3.1,A5,E5.2E2)

END


SUBROUTINE sub(...,...,...)
common filename
character (LEN=35) :: filename

open(333,file="./resultsNEW/Output"//mvalue//".res")    

END
```

So, I want the output file's name to be

```
Output_M1.00E+10_nu03.0_tau0.5_Reff1.00E+03.res
```

but instead, I get

```
Output_M********_nu 3.0_tau0.5_Reff***** .res
```

i.e., it works for the variables nu and tau, but it doesn't with mass and radius...what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you asking what `*********` means in the output?  If so, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15681735) perhaps.  Or why there are problems with the width.

Comment: Perfect, in the question you linked me the "For E format the fieldwidth has to be at least 7 more than the number of decimals" part made the magic!
Thanks!